# Complexity of bubble sort

Tags: java, sorting

I have a simple integer sorting problem at hand and to solve it, I am planning to write a variation of bubble sort. It seems to be working fine but I am not sure about it's complexity in big-O. What it could be ?

```
public class TempBubbleSort 
{

static Integer[] myArray = {10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1};

static int counter = 0;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    for(int anchor=0; anchor<myArray.length; anchor++)
    {
        for(int compare=anchor+1; compare<myArray.length; compare++)
        {
            counter++;
            // sort ascending
            if(myArray[anchor] > myArray[compare])
            {
                int tmp = myArray[compare];
                myArray[compare] = myArray[anchor];
                myArray[anchor] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Comparision Count : "+counter);

    for(int i : myArray)
        System.out.println(i);
}


}
```

Output when you run above is :

```
Comparision Count : 45
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Comment: There already better sorting algorithms which you can just use. Why struggling with writing worse on your own?

Comment: Also note that `static Integer[] myArray = {10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1};` hits an edge case.

Comment: Agreed with @πάνταῥεῖ. I realize that what I had written is more similar selection sort than bubble. And complexity will in closer to selection sort. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly answering your question about what the \$Big-O\$ run-time complexity,

```java
public class TempBubbleSort 
{

static Integer[] myArray = {10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1};

static int counter = 0;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // **This is O(n), as we're touching every point in your array.
    for(int anchor=0; anchor<myArray.length; anchor++)
    {
        // **This is O(n-1), but since we don't care about constants as n grows, we consider this as O(n)
        for(int compare=anchor+1; compare<myArray.length; compare++)
        {
            // **Everything in here then is a bunch of constant operations so we'll just ignore them.
            counter++;
            // sort ascending
            if(myArray[anchor] > myArray[compare])
            {
                int tmp = myArray[compare];
                myArray[compare] = myArray[anchor];
                myArray[anchor] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
    // **So the total of the brunt of your work would be O(n)*O(n) or O(n^2), because for every element in your array n, you touch every other element in your array, so you can look at it as touching n things in your array, n times.

    System.out.println("Comparision Count : "+counter);

    // **In case you're curious, this is also O(n)
    for(int i : myArray)
        System.out.println(i);

    // **Which would bring the grand total to O(n^2+n), again with Big O notation, we only care about what happens as n continues to grow, and since n^2 grows faster than n, as our n gets super big, the second term n becomes insignificant, so we look at this overall total as O(n^2). In fact, for any polynomial time complexity, you can safely drop all terms that are not your largest degree.
}


}
```

In closing, its usually easy to tell the time-complexity of simple iterative functions like this by the number of nested for loops you have, which can be a good rule of thumb for a nice approximate guess for time complexity in a pinch.